# Structured Self-Learning Program for Calculus I & II

Tags: calculus, reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, education

I'm interested in a organised program which comprehensively covers the topics of Calculus I and Calculus II.

I've recently finished taking my secondary school's university-level Calculus I course, however, I am going to take it again during my first year at university.

I take well to highly-structured/linear learning—especially programs which introduce a topic, move you through each individual step of an example problem, and then give you practical applications of the problem-solving process.

Ideally these topics are introduced clearly and sequentially in a manner which builds upon introduced concepts.

Graphically organised programs are very helpful as well (as it gives a good idea of progress, which is incredibly helpful to me).

I am happy to consider any suggestions, which will hopefully fit my given standards fairly well.

Calculus I:
Introduction to differential and integral calculus: including limits, continuity, differentiation and integration of algebraic, trigonometric, logarithmic, exponential, and other transcendental functions

Calculus II:
Expanding methods of integration, including coverage of improper integrals, sequences, infinite series, power series, polar coordinates, and parametric and polar equations.

Comment: Is Calculus II Multivariable Calc?

Comment: Why don't you get a standard textbook and work through that?

Comment: What is calculus I and calculus II? Are these Americanisms? If so you should note that most people on this site are not American.

Comment: @Oliver A quick google search will give you the answers (though these may not be exactly what OP is asking for)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MITOCW is always the best program for self-studying math.

Calculus I

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/

Calculus II

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/

Comment: Beautiful. Have you reviewed these? They seem relatively thorough, I'm just curious.

Comment: I've never used MITOCW to study Calculus but just more advanced topics like Analysis. There are many kind of Calculus classes in MITOCW, so plenty of resources is available.